# mysql problem, there is data in ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 but not in the mysql database

Tags: mysql

My `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` is 2, but whenever I examine the `ib_logfile` the data is present but when i query the database the data is not there e.g. if i do a insert 'xyz' into the db a couple of 1000 times all of the entries are there in the `ib_logfile` but some of them are not there in the db, when retrieved by a query. So all 1000 are there in the `ib_logfile` but only 900 are there in the db. Whatever could be the problem?

I am using toplink and struts 2 for inserting data activity. there is no information in the catalina.out file. Cannot find any information on the internet. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you have transactions that are rolling back and removing your changes. this can happen if, for example, you have auto-commit off and you don't explicitly commit your transactions.